# Projections- Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused doing this simple question, but I need a better explanation.
 Suppose $A$ is a $4\times3$ matrix formed from $4\times4$ identity matrix with its last column removed. Project $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}$ onto the column space of $A$ . What shape is the projection matrix $P$ and what is $P$?

Comment: Someone will probably come along and just dump the answer here for you, but you should try to go through step-by-step yourself. Step 1 is always making sure you understand the definitions. Do you know what the column space of $A$ is?

Comment: In general, if you have a space spanned by the columns of $R=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$  
then the projection of a column vector $v$ on that space is $R(R^TR)^{-1}R^T.v$

Answer (score 1):

There is a general procedure to compute the orthogonal projection of a vector onto a subspace $U$ (in this case, the column space of $A$). It goes like this:

1. Find an orthogonal basis $u_1, \ldots,u_k$ for the subspace (here my $u_i$ are column vectors). Usually this requires Gram-Schmidt.
2. Compute the projection matrix $P$ using the formula 
   $$P = \frac{u_1u_1^T}{u_1^Tu_1}+ \cdots+\frac{u_ku_k^T}{u_k^Tu_k}$$
   (in each fraction above, the numerator is a $n\times n$ matrix and the denominator is a scalar (the norm-squared of the vector).
3. Compute the projection of $v$ onto the subspace by computing the matrix-vector product $Pv$. (note: the fact that $Pv = \text{proj}_U(v)$ is not hard to check. Compare with the formula for projection to a line).

In this case, step 1 and 2 are much simpler than is normally the case, so long as you understand what the column space of $A$ is. So the question really is, do you understand what the column space of $A$ is?